# How to make a histogram from a list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, histogram

I have a list of strings:

```
a = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']
```

I want to make a histogram for displaying the frequency distribution of the letters. I can make a list that contains the count of each letter using following codes:

```
from itertools import groupby
b = [len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(a)]
```

How do I make the histogram? I may have a million such elements in list `a`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Very easy with `Pandas`.

```
import pandas
from collections import Counter
a = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']
letter_counts = Counter(a)
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(letter_counts, orient='index')
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

Notice that `Counter` is making a frequency count, so our plot type is `'bar'` not `'hist'`.

[image: histogram of letter counts]

Answer (score 40):

here's a concise all-pandas approach:

```
a = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']
pd.Series(a).value_counts(sort=False).plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: barplot of counts]

Answer (score 14):

As @notconfusing pointed above this can be solved with Pandas and Counter. If for **any reason you need to not use Pandas** you can get by with only `matplotlib` using the function in the following code:

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']
letter_counts = Counter(a)

def plot_bar_from_counter(counter, ax=None):
    """"
    This function creates a bar plot from a counter.

    :param counter: This is a counter object, a dictionary with the item as the key
     and the frequency as the value
    :param ax: an axis of matplotlib
    :return: the axis wit the object in it
    """

    if ax is None:
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    frequencies = counter.values()
    names = counter.keys()

    x_coordinates = np.arange(len(counter))
    ax.bar(x_coordinates, frequencies, align='center')

    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.FixedLocator(x_coordinates))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FixedFormatter(names))

    return ax

plot_bar_from_counter(letter_counts)
plt.show()
```

Which will produce
[image]

Answer (score 11):

Rather than use `groupby()` (which requires your input to be sorted), use [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter); this doesn't have to create intermediary lists just to count inputs:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(a)
```

You haven't really specified what you consider to be a 'histogram'. Lets assume you wanted to do this on the terminal:

```
width = 120  # Adjust to desired width
longest_key = max(len(key) for key in counts)
graph_width = width - longest_key - 2
widest = counts.most_common(1)[0][1]
scale = graph_width / float(widest)

for key, size in sorted(counts.items()):
    print('{}: {}'.format(key, int(size * scale) * '*'))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']
>>> counts = Counter(a)
>>> width = 120  # Adjust to desired width
>>> longest_key = max(len(key) for key in counts)
>>> graph_width = width - longest_key - 2
>>> widest = counts.most_common(1)[0][1]
>>> scale = graph_width / float(widest)
>>> for key, size in sorted(counts.items()):
...     print('{}: {}'.format(key, int(size * scale) * '*'))
... 
a: *********************************************************************************************
b: **********************************************
c: **********************************************************************
d: ***********************
e: *********************************************************************************************************************
```

More sophisticated tools are found in the [`numpy.histogram()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) and [`matplotlib.pyplot.hist()`](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) functions. These do the tallying for you, with `matplotlib.pyplot.hist()` also providing you with graph output.

Answer (score 6):

## Using numpy

Using numpy 1.9 or greater:

```
import numpy as np
a = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']
labels, counts = np.unique(a,return_counts=True)
```

This can be plotted using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
ticks = range(len(counts))
plt.bar(ticks,counts, align='center')
plt.xticks(ticks, labels)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check out `matplotlib.pyplot.bar`. There is also `numpy.histogram` which is more flexible if you want wider bins.

Answer (score 1):

Simple and effective way to make character histrogram in python

```html
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from collections import Counter



a = []
count =0
d = dict()
filename = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    for word in f:
        for letter  in word:
            if letter not in d:
                d[letter] = 1
            else:
                d[letter] +=1
num = Counter(d)
x = list(num.values())
y = list(num.keys())

x_coordinates = np.arange(len(num.keys()))
plt.bar(x_coordinates,x)
plt.xticks(x_coordinates,y)
plt.show()
print x,y
```

Answer (score 1):

this was a while ago so i'm not sure if you still need help but other people might so i'm here. if you're allowed to use matplotlib i think there's a much simpler solution!

```
a = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(a) #gives you a histogram of your array 'a'
plt.show() #finishes out the plot
```

this should get you a nice histogram! there are also more edits you can do to clean up the graph if you'd like

Answer (score 1):

- Technically, this is a frequency count of discrete categorical values.

  - A histogram is a frequency distribution of continuous numeric values.
- This can be accomplished by passing the list to either the `x=` or `y=` parameter of [`seaborn.countplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html), [`seaborn.histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html), or [`sns.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) with `kind='hist'`.

  - [seaborn](/questions/tagged/seaborn) is a high-level API for [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib).
- See [How to add value labels on a bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) to add value label annotations to the top of the bars.

```py
import seaborn as sns

a = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']
```

```py
ax = sns.countplot(x=a)
```

[image]

```py
ax = sns.countplot(y=a)
```

[image]

```py
ax = sns.histplot(x=a)
```

[image]

```py
g = sns.displot(kind='hist', x=a)
```

[image]