# How to add value labels on a bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I'm creating a bar chart, and I can't figure out how to add value labels on the bars (in the center of the bar, or just above it).

I believe the solution is either with 'text' or 'annotate', but I:
a) don't know which one to use (and generally speaking, haven't figured out when to use which).
b) can't see to get either to present the value labels.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pd.set_option('display.mpl_style', 'default') 
%matplotlib inline

# Bring some raw data.
frequencies = [6, 16, 75, 160, 244, 260, 145, 73, 16, 4, 1]

# In my original code I create a series and run on that, 
# so for consistency I create a series from the list.
freq_series = pd.Series(frequencies)

x_labels = [108300.0, 110540.0, 112780.0, 115020.0, 117260.0, 119500.0, 
            121740.0, 123980.0, 126220.0, 128460.0, 130700.0]

# Plot the figure.
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
fig = freq_series.plot(kind='bar')
fig.set_title('Amount Frequency')
fig.set_xlabel('Amount ($)')
fig.set_ylabel('Frequency')
fig.set_xticklabels(x_labels)
```

[image]

How can I add value labels on the bars (in the center of the bar, or just above it)?

Comment: Matplotlib has a demo: https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html

Comment: For `matplotlib >= 3.4.2` use `.bar_label`, as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804). Applies to `pandas` and `seaborn`, which use `matplotlib`.

Answer (score 164):

Firstly `freq_series.plot` returns an axis *not* a figure so to make my answer a little more clear I've changed your given code to refer to it as `ax` rather than `fig` to be more consistent with other code examples.

You can get the list of the bars produced in the plot from the `ax.patches` member. Then you can use the technique demonstrated in [this `matplotlib` gallery example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html) to add the labels using the [`ax.text`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text) method.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Bring some raw data.
frequencies = [6, 16, 75, 160, 244, 260, 145, 73, 16, 4, 1]
# In my original code I create a series and run on that,
# so for consistency I create a series from the list.
freq_series = pd.Series(frequencies)

x_labels = [
    108300.0,
    110540.0,
    112780.0,
    115020.0,
    117260.0,
    119500.0,
    121740.0,
    123980.0,
    126220.0,
    128460.0,
    130700.0,
]

# Plot the figure.
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
ax = freq_series.plot(kind="bar")
ax.set_title("Amount Frequency")
ax.set_xlabel("Amount ($)")
ax.set_ylabel("Frequency")
ax.set_xticklabels(x_labels)

rects = ax.patches

# Make some labels.
labels = [f"label{i}" for i in range(len(rects))]

for rect, label in zip(rects, labels):
    height = rect.get_height()
    ax.text(
        rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height + 5, label, ha="center", va="bottom"
    )

plt.show()
```

This produces a labeled plot that looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 98):

Based on a feature mentioned in [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47812553/2161004) I have found a very generally applicable solution for placing labels on a bar chart.

Other solutions unfortunately do not work in many cases, because the spacing between label and bar is either [given in absolute units of the bars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28931750/2161004) or is [scaled by the height of the bar](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html). The former only works for a narrow range of values and the latter gives inconsistent spacing within one plot. Neither works well with logarithmic axes.

The solution I propose works independent of scale (i.e. for small and large numbers) and even correctly places labels for negative values and with logarithmic scales because it uses the visual unit `points` for offsets.

I have added a negative number to showcase the correct placement of labels in such a case.

The value of the height of each bar is used as a label for it. Other labels can easily be used with [Simon's `for rect, label in zip(rects, labels)` snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28931750/2161004).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Bring some raw data.
frequencies = [6, -16, 75, 160, 244, 260, 145, 73, 16, 4, 1]

# In my original code I create a series and run on that,
# so for consistency I create a series from the list.
freq_series = pd.Series.from_array(frequencies)

x_labels = [108300.0, 110540.0, 112780.0, 115020.0, 117260.0, 119500.0,
            121740.0, 123980.0, 126220.0, 128460.0, 130700.0]

# Plot the figure.
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
ax = freq_series.plot(kind='bar')
ax.set_title('Amount Frequency')
ax.set_xlabel('Amount ($)')
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
ax.set_xticklabels(x_labels)


def add_value_labels(ax, spacing=5):
    """Add labels to the end of each bar in a bar chart.

    Arguments:
        ax (matplotlib.axes.Axes): The matplotlib object containing the axes
            of the plot to annotate.
        spacing (int): The distance between the labels and the bars.
    """

    # For each bar: Place a label
    for rect in ax.patches:
        # Get X and Y placement of label from rect.
        y_value = rect.get_height()
        x_value = rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2

        # Number of points between bar and label. Change to your liking.
        space = spacing
        # Vertical alignment for positive values
        va = 'bottom'

        # If value of bar is negative: Place label below bar
        if y_value < 0:
            # Invert space to place label below
            space *= -1
            # Vertically align label at top
            va = 'top'

        # Use Y value as label and format number with one decimal place
        label = "{:.1f}".format(y_value)

        # Create annotation
        ax.annotate(
            label,                      # Use `label` as label
            (x_value, y_value),         # Place label at end of the bar
            xytext=(0, space),          # Vertically shift label by `space`
            textcoords="offset points", # Interpret `xytext` as offset in points
            ha='center',                # Horizontally center label
            va=va)                      # Vertically align label differently for
                                        # positive and negative values.


# Call the function above. All the magic happens there.
add_value_labels(ax)

plt.savefig("image.png")
```

*Edit: I have extracted the relevant functionality in a function, as suggested by [barnhillec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1194651/barnhillec).*

This produces the following output:

[image: Bar chart with automatically placed labels on each bar]

And with logarithmic scale (and some adjustment to the input data to showcase logarithmic scaling), this is the result:

[image: Bar chart with logarithmic scale with automatically placed labels on each bar]

Answer (score 81):

#### Enhanced Bar Chart Annotations with `matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label`

##### Introduction

The [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html) function, introduced in [`matplotlib v3.4.0`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.4.0.html#new-automatic-labeling-for-bar-charts), simplifies the process of adding labels to bar charts. This guide explores how to use this feature to make your data visualizations more informative and easier to understand.

##### Key Features and Usage

- **Label Positioning**: Labels are positioned at the bar 'edge' by default, with an option to place them 'center' via `label_type`.
- **Customization**: Additional customization is possible by passing kwargs to [`Axes.annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate), allowing adjustments of [`text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) attributes like `color`, `rotation`, and `fontsize`.
- **Format Strings**: The `fmt` argument now supports {}-style format strings, introduced in the [`matplotlib 3.7 Update`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.7.0.html#additional-format-string-options-in-bar-label), for dynamic label formatting.
- **Conditional Formatting**: Labels can be conditionally formatted with the `fmt` parameter for greater data presentation flexibility.

##### Understanding `ax.containers`

`ax.containers` holds `BarContainer` artists, crucial for label placement in bar charts. It's simple for single-level plots but contains multiple objects for grouped or stacked plots, reflecting their structure.

##### Practical Examples

1. **Basic Annotation**:
   Create and label a simple bar chart from a DataFrame.

   ```py
   # Creating a DataFrame and plotting a bar chart
   import pandas as pd
   df = pd.DataFrame({'Frequency': frequencies}, index=x_labels)
   ax = df.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(12, 8), title='Amount Frequency', xlabel='Amount ($)', ylabel='Frequency', legend=False)
   # Adding labels to the chart
   ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], label_type='edge')
   # Adjusting margins for clarity
   ax.margins(y=0.1)
   ```

   [image]

   <sup>The resulting plots from the seaborn and `Axes.bar` examples closely mirror the one demonstrated above.</sup>
2. **Custom Appearance**:
   Customize the appearance of bar chart labels with parameters from [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html).

   ```py
   # Customizing label appearance
   ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], label_type='edge', color='red', rotation=90, fontsize=7, padding=3)
   ```

   [image]
3. **Seaborn [Axes-level Plot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions)**:
   Annotate a seaborn barplot.

   ```py
   # Plotting and annotating using seaborn
   import seaborn as sns
   fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
   sns.barplot(x=x_labels, y=frequencies, ax=ax)
   ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], label_type='edge')
   ax.margins(y=0.1)
   ```
4. **Seaborn [Figure-level Plot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions)**:
   Annotate seaborn's figure-level bar plots.

   ```py
   df = pd.DataFrame({'Frequency': frequencies, 'amount': x_labels})
   # Annotating seaborn's figure-level plots
   g = sns.catplot(kind='bar', data=df, x='amount', y='Frequency', height=6, aspect=1.5)
   for ax in g.axes.flat:
       ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], label_type='edge')
       ax.margins(y=0.1)
   ```
5. **Using [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar.html)**:
   A similar approach can be taken using [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) for direct plotting.

   ```py
   # Plotting with matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   xticks = range(len(frequencies))  # Setting up xticks
   fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
   ax.bar(x=xticks, height=frequencies)  # Creating the bar chart
   ax.set_xticks(xticks, x_labels)  # Labeling xticks
   ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], label_type='edge')  # Annotating bars
   ax.margins(y=0.1)  # Padding for clarity
   ```

##### Conditional Formatting with `fmt`

- Exclude zero or negative values, showing labels for positive values only.

  ```py
  # Excluding zero or negative values from labels
  ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], fmt=lambda x: x if x > 0 else '', label_type='edge')
  ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], fmt=lambda x: f'{x:0.0f}' if x > 0 else '', label_type='edge')
  ```
- Use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for more complex conditional formatting.

  ```py
  # Using np.where for conditional label formatting
  import numpy as np
  ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], fmt=lambda x: np.where(x > 0, x, ''), label_type='center')
  ```

##### Multiple Bar Containers

Handle complex charts, such as grouped or stacked bars, with multiple bar containers.

```py
# Iterating through multiple containers for annotation in complex charts
for c in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(c, fmt=lambda x: np.where(x > 0, x, ''), label_type='center')
```

##### Extensive Label Customization

For scenarios demanding more intricate label customization beyond default capabilities, specifying manual labels using the `labels` parameter affords detailed control, as shown in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60895640/7758804), and the following code snippet:

```py
# Generating custom labels for each bar, omitting labels for values less than 0
labels = [f'{h:.1f}%' if (h := v.get_height()) > 0 else '' for v in ax.containers[0]]
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], labels=labels, label_type='center')
```

##### Compatibility

This code has been tested with Python 3.12.0, pandas 2.2.1, matplotlib 3.8.1, and seaborn 0.13.2.

---

### Additional Resources

For a deeper dive into formatting options and additional examples, the [Bar Label Demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_label_demo.html) page, and the following answers, serve as valuable resources, offering additional guidance for enhancing bar charts.

#### Answers with `label=` Parameter

| **Label Answers** | **Label Answers** |
| --- | --- |
| [Horizontal stacked bar plot and add labels to each section](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64202669/7758804) | [How to annotate a stacked bar plot and add legend labels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68785457/7758804) |
| [How to add multiple annotations to a barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61718351/7758804) | [How to customize bar annotations to not show selected values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69933760/7758804) |
| [How to plot a horizontal stacked bar with annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63148388/7758804) | [How to annotate bar plots when adding error bars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70339089/7758804) |
| [How to align annotations at the end of a horizontal bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63478759/7758804) | [How to add multiple data labels in a bar chart in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69239502) |
| [How to annotate bar chart with values different to those from get_height()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70238576) | [Pandas bar how to label desired values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70237904) |

#### Stacked Bar Charts

| **Stacked Bar Answers** | **Stacked Bar Answers** |
| --- | --- |
| [How to annotate each segment of a stacked bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63856446/7758804) | [Stacked Bar Chart with Centered Labels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60895640/7758804) |
| [How to create and annotate a stacked proportional bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70523793/7758804) | [How to calculate percent by row and annotate 100 percent stacked bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70294171) |
| [Stacked bars are unexpectedly annotated with the sum of bar heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70280423) | [How to plot a stacked bar with annotations for multiple groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69873708) |
| [How to annotate only one category of a stacked bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68641029) |  |

#### Grouped Bar Charts

| **Grouped Bar Answers** | **Grouped Bar Answers** |
| --- | --- |
| [How to plot and annotate grouped bars in seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63220988/7758804) | [How to plot and annotate a grouped bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63493864/7758804) |
| [How to plot and annotate grouped bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70250129) | [How to display percentage above grouped bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70178446) |
| [How to plot grouped bars in the correct order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68721443) | [How to get a grouped bar plot of categorical data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68594262) |
| [How to create grouped bar plots in a single figure from a wide dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68471474) | [How to plot multiple bars grouped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69170710) |
| [How to plot grouped bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69442810) |  |

#### Other Answers with `bar_label`

| **Other Answers** | **Other Answers** |
| --- | --- |
| [How to wrap long tick labels in a seaborn figure-level plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68954616) | [How to annotate barplot with percent by hue/legend group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68851673) |
| [How to add percentages on top of bars in seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68851142) | [How to plot percentage with seaborn distplot / histplot / displot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68850867) |
| [Problem with plotting two lists with different sizes using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68716523) | [How to Increase subplot text size and add custom bar plot annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68639839) |
| [How to determine if the last value in all columns is greater than n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68086418) | [How to plot element count and add annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67961959) |
| [Seaborn Catplot set values over the bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67594395) | [Matplotlib pie chart label does not match value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69033269) |
| [How to horizontally center a bar plot annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63211300) | [How to Resolve 'alpha' Parameter Display Issue in pyplot.grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69125398) |
| [How to set ticklabel rotation and add bar annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69899208) | [How to aggregate group metrics and plot data with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69888266) |
| [How to annotate a stackplot or area plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69508502) |  |

Answer (score 58):

Building off the above (great!) answer, we can also make a horizontal bar plot with just a few adjustments:

```
# Bring some raw data.
frequencies = [6, -16, 75, 160, 244, 260, 145, 73, 16, 4, 1]

freq_series = pd.Series(frequencies)

y_labels = [108300.0, 110540.0, 112780.0, 115020.0, 117260.0, 119500.0, 
            121740.0, 123980.0, 126220.0, 128460.0, 130700.0]

# Plot the figure.
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
ax = freq_series.plot(kind='barh')
ax.set_title('Amount Frequency')
ax.set_xlabel('Frequency')
ax.set_ylabel('Amount ($)')
ax.set_yticklabels(y_labels)
ax.set_xlim(-40, 300) # expand xlim to make labels easier to read

rects = ax.patches

# For each bar: Place a label
for rect in rects:
    # Get X and Y placement of label from rect.
    x_value = rect.get_width()
    y_value = rect.get_y() + rect.get_height() / 2

    # Number of points between bar and label. Change to your liking.
    space = 5
    # Vertical alignment for positive values
    ha = 'left'

    # If value of bar is negative: Place label left of bar
    if x_value < 0:
        # Invert space to place label to the left
        space *= -1
        # Horizontally align label at right
        ha = 'right'

    # Use X value as label and format number with one decimal place
    label = "{:.1f}".format(x_value)

    # Create annotation
    plt.annotate(
        label,                      # Use `label` as label
        (x_value, y_value),         # Place label at end of the bar
        xytext=(space, 0),          # Horizontally shift label by `space`
        textcoords="offset points", # Interpret `xytext` as offset in points
        va='center',                # Vertically center label
        ha=ha)                      # Horizontally align label differently for
                                    # positive and negative values.

plt.savefig("image.png")
```

[image: horizontal bar plot with annotations]

Answer (score 53):

If you want to just label the data points above the bar, you could use plt.annotate()

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = [1,2,3,4,5,]
s = [i**2 for i in n]
line = plt.bar(n,s)
plt.xlabel('Number')
plt.ylabel("Square")

for i in range(len(s)):
    plt.annotate(str(s[i]), xy=(n[i],s[i]), ha='center', va='bottom')

plt.show()
```

By specifying a horizontal and vertical alignment of `'center'` and `'bottom'` respectively one can get centered annotations.

[image: a labelled bar chart]

Answer (score 2):

I needed the bar labels too, note that my y-axis is having a zoomed view using limits on y axis. The default calculations for putting the labels on top of the bar still works using height (use_global_coordinate=False in the example). But I wanted to show that the labels can be put in the bottom of the graph too in zoomed view using global coordinates in [matplotlib 3.0.2](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html). Hope it help someone.

```py
def autolabel(rects,data):
    """
    Attach a text label above each bar displaying its height
    """
    c = 0
    initial = 0.091
    offset = 0.205
    use_global_coordinate = True
    
    if use_global_coordinate:
        for i in data:        
            ax.text(initial+offset*c, 0.05, str(i), horizontalalignment='center',
                    verticalalignment='center', transform=ax.transAxes,fontsize=8)
            c=c+1
    else:
        for rect,i in zip(rects,data):
            height = rect.get_height()
            ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., height,str(i),ha='center', va='bottom')
```

[image: Example output]

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to add Datapoints above the bars, you could easily do it with:

```
 for i in range(len(frequencies)): # your number of bars
    plt.text(x = x_values[i]-0.25, #takes your x values as horizontal positioning argument 
    y = y_values[i]+1, #takes your y values as vertical positioning argument 
    s = data_labels[i], # the labels you want to add to the data
    size = 9) # font size of datalabels
```