# How to convert multiple dataframe columns (of same type) into a single list or series

Tags: pandas

Suppose have pandas dataframe of the form

```
col0 col1 col2 col3
---------------------
a0   a1   a2   a3
b0   b1   None None
c0   c1   c2   c3
```

Would like to be able to get a list or pandas Series of some specified selection of these columns, eg.

```
in: stack(df[['col1', 'col3']])

out: 
a0
a3
b0
c0
c3
```

(notice that in this example `None` values are skipped). Tried using [stack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas-dataframe-stack), but did not seem to be quite what was needed. Any advice or suggestions on how I can get dataframe columns into this form would be appreciated.(Ultimately want to get a histogram of the different values (via https://stackoverflow.com/a/28419258/8236733)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.unstack()` to turn them into a `MultiIndex`ed series, drop the nulls, and then just take the `np.array` or a list:

```
In [69]: df[['col1', 'col3']].unstack().dropna().values
Out[69]: array(['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'a3', 'c3'], dtype=object)

In [70]: df[['col1', 'col3']].unstack().dropna().tolist()
Out[70]: ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'a3', 'c3']
```