# plt.histogram on categorial data and fixed categories

Tags: matplotlib

It's great the plt.hist does the right thing with categorical data!  Very cool.

But how do I specify the bins and their order, like I can do with numerical data?  I want to show a bunch of histograms, all with the same bins and labels, regardless whether any particular set of data has all the bins. I want the same order for the bins, and I want the bins to be there, even if this particular set of data has no data for a label.

I tried setting the first few entries in each dataset to my four known categories, hoping that would force things to behave.  But no such luck.

```
data = [f'foo_{i}' for i in np.random.randint(4, size=10)]
plt.hist(data);
```

Thanks.

--- Malcolm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a histogram from a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418988/how-to-make-a-histogram-from-a-list-of-strings)

Comment: The easiest solution involves pandas, with a data that is explicitly categorical.  `df = pd.Dataframe({'x':pd.Categorical(data, categories=['foo_0, foo_1, foo_2, foo_3])})` and then use `df.hist()`.  By explicitly setting the categories, a consistent ordering is enforced.